# How to get filtered records from Sql Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Consider that I have two tables.

One is "Table1" as shown below.

[image]

One more table is "Table2" as shown below.

[image]

Now here what I need is, I need all the records from Table1 those ID's are not in Table2's Reference column.

Please guide me how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to do it with your current schema (impossible to use indexes):

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table2
    WHERE CONCAT(',', Table2.Reference, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', Table1.ID, ',%')
)
```

How this works is by completely wrapping every value in the `Reference` column with commas. You will end up with `,2,3,` and `,7,8,9,` for your sample data. Then you can safely search for `,<Table1.ID>,` within that string.

---

How to really do it:

Normalize your database, and get rid of those ugly, useless comma-separated lists.

Fix your table2 to be:

```
 SlNo | Reference
------+-----------
    1 |        2
    1 |        3
    2 |        7
    2 |        8
    2 |        9
```

and add a table2Names as:

```
 SlNo | Name
------+---------
    1 | Test
    2 | Test 2
```

Then you can simply do:

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Reference = Table1.ID)
```